# How to find Taylor of more complicated functions easily

Tags: sequences-and-series

If  $$ f(x) = \frac{e^{(n+1)x} - e^{x}}{e^{x} - 1}$$

I want the expansion of this function around x=1, but it seems to be quite complicated to do. Are there any 'tricks' that are applicable to find Taylor of more complicated functions?

One thing that I did consider, was writing the co-efficents using leibniz product rule. As in:

$$ a_k = \frac{1}{k!} \lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{j=0}^{j=k}  \binom{n}{k} \frac{d^j}{dx^j} (e^{(n+1)x} - e^{x}) \frac{dx^{k-j}}{dx^{k-j}} (e^{x} - 1)^{-1}$$

i.e:
$$ a_k = \frac{1}{k!} \lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{j=0}^{j=k}  \binom{n}{k} [(n+1)^je^{(n+1)(x)} - e^{x}]  \frac{dx^{k-j}}{dx^{k-j}} (e^{x} - 1)^{-1}$$

Not sure how I would simplify it any further or if there is an even simpler way.

Comment: Why to write $\;n+(1)x\;$ and not simply $\;n+x\;$ ? Or did you mean $\;(n+1)x\;$ ...?

Comment: second one, I will fix it

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :**

$$\frac{e^{(n+1)x}-e^x}{e^x-1}=e^x\frac{e^{nx}-1}{e^x-1} = e^x \left( 1 + e^x + ... + e^{(n-1)x} \right) = \sum_{k=1}^n e^{kx}$$

Answer (score 2):

I don't really have a general answer, but this one specifically simplifies to a geometric series:
$$ f(x) = \frac{e^{(n+1)x} - e^x}{e^x - 1} = e^x \frac{e^{nx} - 1}{e^x - 1} = e^x \frac{1 - e^{nx}}{1 - e^x} = e^x \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} e^{kx}. $$

Then, you can put in the Taylor series of $e^x$ to get a power series of the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \frac{e^{(n+1)x} - e^x}{e^x - 1} =\sum_{k=1}^n e^{kx}=\sum_{k=1}^n e^k\,e^{k(x-1)}=\sum_{k=1}^n e^k e^{ky}$$ Around $y=0$
$$e^{ky}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac {k^m}{m!} y^m=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac {k^m}{m!} (x-1)^m$$

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n  \sum_{m=0}^\infty e^k\frac {k^m}{m!} (x-1)^m$$

*Just for your curiosity.*

If we switch the order of summation
$$f(x)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\text{Li}_{-m}(e)-e^{n+1} \Phi (e,-m,n+1)}{m!}(x-1)^m $$ where appear the polylogarithm and  the Lerch transcendent functions.